# NetSuite: SuiteTalk Retrieve Journal Entries lines

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

I try to retrieve Journal Entry lines using SuiteTalk without success.
I'm able to retrieve the journal entry with a TransctionSearchBasic passing the journal id as criteria, but i'm unable to get all the journal lines details.
Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

In your search preferences, set bodyFieldsOnly to False. This will give you the lines on the record as well as the header data.